# How to override the behavior of Spring @Autowired

Tags: unit-testing, spring, dependency-injection

A little background:

I am Using Spring 2.5, and specifically Spring IOC and annotations.

I am using `@Autowired` in my code (the Autowiring is done by type)
and use  `@Component` for exposing classes to the automatic wiring.

The situation described below arose while I tried to test my code.

Now to the problem:

Note: I use a different Spring Context for the Test environment.

I have a class `FOO` which is `@Autowired` but in the test context I want to use a different class of the same type `MockFoo` (extends `FOO`).

The Spring setup of course fails automatically due to multiple options for the Dependency Injection of the `FOO` class (both `FOO` and `MockFOO` comply to the Type check).

I am looking for a way to inject the test bean instead of the original bean.

I expected Spring to allow using the Context configuration file to override a bean injection or to order Spring not to autowire a specific bean.

BUT

All these options seem to exists only for the beans which were originally defined in the Spring Context Configuration file.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`ReflectionTestUtils`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html) to manually set the Mock in place of the autowired dependency (for that purpose your mock must not be spring managed, so that no ambiguity exists)

Comment: this is a good solution when you do not have the same instance injected to multiple classes - but in a big project where a class acts as a service provider(it is a singleton) and is injected to many classes, i hope there is some easier/better solution to avoid injecting each class that uses the original

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is quite old but a I think an answer might still be useful for others.

Since you probably do not want to mix both Foo and MockFoo within your context, I would suggest to remove Foo from the component-scanning. This could be done for example by specifying [include/exclude filters](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch04s12.html#beans-scanning-filters) on the `<context:component-scan>`.

However if you are implementing unit tests, I would rather suggest not using a Spring context and just implementing "pure" unit tests by injecting mock-ups of the dependencies manually, so that you are only testing a single class. This can be achieved more easily by using a mocking framework like [Mockito](http://www.mockito.org/).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Didier.  Here is an example of how you can exclude the implementations that you want to mock in your test application context.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company" >
    <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com\.abc\.service\.XDaoImpl"/>    
</context:component-scan>
```

Include this application context in your test as follows :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/applicationContext-test.xml"})
public class MyTest {....}
```

Comment: Good answer, I'd really go with this one. Don't forget that you can always use @Qualifier(name="someBean") on your to be injected bean and @Resource(name="someBean") on the field where you want that specific bean instance to be injected.