# How to make Spring @autowired annotation to pick a certain type without using @Qualifier?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

Is there a way to specify the default type for Spring @autowired annotation? For example, I have bean ValidatorA and bean ValidatorB that extends ValidatorA.
The ValidatorA is used in some other places and is injected using @autowired.
Is there a way to force Spring to inject ValidatorB instead of ValidatorA without changing the existing code? 
The only solution I found at [How to override the behavior of Spring @Autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843281/how-to-override-the-behavior-of-spring-autowired) suggests to exclude ValidatorA from the context.
Is there any other way?
For example, with Guice I would just bind the ValidatorA.class to ValidatorB.class and that will do exactly what I need.

I have no problem to add @Qualifier to ValidatorB but ValidatorA should stay unchanged.
Guice provides ability to define "Providers", is there something similar in Spring? Maybe with @Configuration annotation?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use `primary` indicator there. If your bean is defined through annotation, add `@Primary` to `ValidatorB` definition. If you are using xml config add `primary="true"` to `<bean>` definition.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like s nice easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

*Is there a way to force Spring to inject ValidatorB instead of ValidatorA without changing the existing code?*

**Without changing the code**, I doubt it very much. You could change the app context or alter the code something like this :

```
@Component
@Qualifier("B")
public class ValidatorB extends ValidatorA {
}
```

and then inject like so (there are [other syntactic options](http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2011/08/spring-injection-with-resource-and-autowired/) as well)

```
@Resource
@Qualifier("B")
private ValidatorA validatorB;
```