# Injecting a mock in Spring application context creates a copy

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I have a test class that looks like this :

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = RecipesApplicationTest.class) // This test class will configure its own context
@ComponentScan("com.mysmartfridge.domain.recipes") // Scan recipes domain package so that domain services are available
@Import(RecipesApplication.class) // Load the bean that we want to test.
public class RecipesApplicationTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SCR = new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule SMR = new SpringMethodRule();

    @Autowired
    private RecipesRepository recipesRepository;

    private final RecipesRepository recipesRepositoryMock = Mockito.mock(RecipesRepository.class); // final mocks because they are given to spring context.

    // Get the service to test from the context
    @Autowired
    RecipesApplication recipesApplication;

    @Test
    public void addingARecipeShouldMakeItAvailableInRandomRecipes() {
        //given
        RecipeDto dto = new RecipeDto();
        dto.title="test";
        dto.ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
        dto.steps = new ArrayList<>();

        final List<Recipe> recipesInMock = new ArrayList<>();
        Mockito.when(recipesRepository.save(Mockito.any(Recipe.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<Recipe>() {
            @Override
            public Recipe answer(InvocationOnMock aInvocation) throws Throwable {
                Recipe arg = aInvocation.getArgumentAt(0, Recipe.class);
                recipesInMock.add(arg);
                return arg;
            }
        });

        Mockito.when(recipesRepository.findAll()).thenAnswer(new Answer<List<Recipe>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Recipe> answer(InvocationOnMock aInvocation) throws Throwable {
                return recipesInMock;
            }
        });


        //when
        dto = recipesApplication.createRecipe(dto);
        RecipeDto randomDto = recipesApplication.findRandomRecipe();

        //then
        Assertions.assertThat(randomDto).isEqualTo(dto);
    }

    // Inject the recipeRepository mock in the context
    @Bean
    RecipesRepository recipesRepository() {
        return recipesRepositoryMock;
    }

}
```

My problem is that the two fields recipesRepositoryMock and recipesRepository are not the same object. Thus, if i try to replace recipesRepository with recipesRepositoryMock when setting up my answers (i.e. if I do `when(recipesRepositoryMock.save()).thenAnswer(...)`), it doesn't work, then custom answer is never called.

I would like to be able to get rid of the @Autowired recipesRepository which is kind of a duplicate with recipesRepositoryMock...

Is it because of a proxy added by spring around my bean ?

Comment: when you say 'it doesn't work', what exactly happens? Is your mock not injected to your service? Or do you see the repository in the service as null? Or some other exception? Or is it just the assertion failure?

Comment: What doesn't work is that the call to `thenAnswer(...)` does add the answer to recipesRepositoryMock, but not to `recipesRepository`, even though I expect them to be the same object (with maybe a spring proxy on top of it).

Comment: what I do in my unit tests is manually create instance of the class to be tested with the mock injected, like `Service service = new Service(mockRepository);`. Works like a charm and is more readable.

Comment: something you could try, remove the global mocked repository and in the bean declaration do `return Mockito.mock(RecipesRepository.class);`.

Comment: @RahulSharma: That's Arthur's answer. That's what I'll do if there's no better solution.

Comment: Ou, sorry. Should have seen the answers first.

Answer (score 2):

You could better remove 
`private final RecipesRepository recipesRepositoryMock = Mockito.mock(RecipesRepository.class);`

If you want to mock a Spring bean then you have to create it for Spring as use `@Autowired`.

So you test could look like:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = RecipesApplicationTest.class) // This test class will configure its own context
@ComponentScan("com.mysmartfridge.domain.recipes") // Scan recipes domain package so that domain services are available
@Import(RecipesApplication.class) // Load the bean that we want to test.
public class RecipesApplicationTest {

  @ClassRule
  public static final SpringClassRule SCR = new SpringClassRule();

  @Rule
  public final SpringMethodRule SMR = new SpringMethodRule();

  @Autowired
  private RecipesRepository recipesRepository; 

  // Get the service to test from the context
  @Autowired
  RecipesApplication recipesApplication;

  @Test
  public void addingARecipeShouldMakeItAvailableInRandomRecipes() {
   // your test 
  }

  // Inject the recipeRepository mock in the context
  @Bean
  RecipesRepository recipesRepository() {
    return Mockito.mock(RecipesRepository.class);
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing at the moment. It's a fine compromise. The only problem is that I find it slightly less clear when reading my tests because the mock initialization is hidden away from the field that I use in the tests.

Comment: By the way,  if you really need only to test how two classes collaborate, then  you may use `@InjectMocks` and don't load Spring context at all. May be this [post](http://www.jayway.com/2012/02/25/mockito-and-dependency-injection/) could help you.

Comment: My example in the post is simplified. I know the standard way to do it with injectMocks and all, but what I want is to test several classes in collaboration for a single use case. Sometimes the mocks are not a direct dependency of the class that I'm testing, they can be a transitive dependency, that's why I need to load the context. I only mock repositories to avoid hitting a DB.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to rely on auto-wiring so that Spring correctly injects the `RecipesRepository` instance as a dependency into `RecipesApplication`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843281/how-to-override-the-behavior-of-spring-autowired) seems to be similar to yours. That being said, I'm hesitant to declare a duplicate because you may not have make use of something like `[ReflectionTestUtils][2]`. Rather, try just deleting the `recipesRepository` field in `RecipesApplicationTest`, keeping `recipesRepositoryMock` field. But, before the `dto = recipesApplication.createRecipe(dto)` line, try to see if you can manually inject the `recipesRepositoryMock` into `recipesApplication` via a call like `recipesApplication.setRecipesRepository(recipesRepositoryMock)` or something similar.

Comment: I can't do that because the repository could be a transitive dependency. For example, RecipesApplication depends on IngredientParser, which itself depends on recipesRepository. I need my mock to be in the spring context.