# Setting @Autowired(required=false) globally during spring-boot test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I can't get the classic XML config

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
        <property name="requiredParameterValue" value="false" />
    </bean>
```

to work in spring-boot test. I've tried the equivalent Java Style

```
@Bean
    public AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor annotation() {
        AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor annotation = new AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
        annotation.setRequiredParameterValue(false);
        return annotation;
}
```

also to no avail.

I'm just trying to find a solution to cherry-pick the beans I need for unit testing.

Here's the code I'm using in the test itself:

```
@Rollback
@SpringApplicationConfiguration({PackageServiceTestConfiguration.class, DatabaseConfiguration.class, MybatisConfiguration.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class PackageServiceTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {...}
```

The content of `PackageServiceTestConfiguration.class` (Database and mybatis are the config part of the apps itself what I need to perform my test

```
@Configuration 
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.project.api.permission.service",
    includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(Service.class))
@ImportResource("classpath:testContext.xml")
public class PackageServiceTestConfiguration {}
```

`testContext.xml` contains some test fixtures and the failing `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` configuration

Thanks to `@ComponentScan` I can filter down to the package for which component to configure, but this is still not as convenient as XML where I can actually define each of the bean I need with a one liner.

I still need to make the `@Autowired` component not required globally for test, and I can't find a way to do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843281/how-to-override-the-behavior-of-spring-autowired

Comment: Still a classic problem five years later. I don't want to mock dependencies I don't need during test though, I just want to be able to not provide them.I can't believe there's no way to disable @Autowired(required=true) globally, this would be so helpful for test.